# Does the campaign screen still show a higher difficulty completed if I start a new campaign on a lower setting?

Tags: starcraft-2

Currently, my Campaign load screen shows:

> Difficulty Completed: Brutal

For both WoL and HoTS. However, I wish to re-play the campaign on a lower difficulty without having it lose this little reminder, as it was quite hard to complete them on this difficulty.

I know I can just 'replay' missions, but that is not what I want to do. I wish to try out different mission paths & strategies in order to try and get some of the harder achievements: by using different units that I hadn't unlocked in my previous 'Brutal' runthrough. I also wish to record parts of the campaign including cutscenes & Hyperion crew interactions etc.

So, does restarting the campaign on a lower difficulty setting change this screen to show a lower 'Difficulty completed' setting?

Comment: I don't have the game or else I'd try this myself, but you can probably back up all your game data, try it, and then restore the backup. I'm guessing that info isn't stored online.

Comment: Don't know about the load screen, but the one on your profile will show the highest campaign difficulty you completed for each expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the campaign screen will show the difficulty that you completed the last mission at as this is where you are continuing from.

So if you complete a mission on brutal say, then quit campaign it will say brutal. But if you then replay that mission on normal from the archive, then quit the campaign then it will say normal on the campaign screen.

However on your profile it will always show the highest difficulty that you completed the campaign at, and has a cool picture to go with it so everyone can witness your might!

Answer (score 0):

No, under your profile it will always display your highest difficulty achievement. When you go to continue the campaign however, it will prompt you with 'Continue campaign on X Difficulty' (Don't let that scare you).

The same method you use to access older missions to 'replay' them, is the same method you can use to choose different campaign paths -> Choosing to side with the Protoss instead of the Doctor.

The Media Blitz hidden level is the only exception to this. If you replay Media blitz and gather the data from the science facility, you will not unlock the ability to play the level, you must do this from the actual campaign path.